# SyncFusion WPF ComboBox in Grid- How to set display text on OnCommitCellInfo event

Tags: c#, wpf, syncfusion

I have a SyncFusion ComboBox dynamically added in SynckFusion:GridControl with following code:

```
    SchoolGrid.Model[rowIndex, columnIndex].CellType = "ComboBox";
    SchoolGrid.Model[rowIndex, columnIndex].ItemsSource = itemSource;
    SchoolGrid.Model[rowIndex, columnIndex].DisplayMember = "FullDistrictName";
    SchoolGrid.Model[rowIndex, columnIndex].ValueMember = "FullDistrictName";
    SchoolGrid.Model[rowIndex, columnIndex].CellValue = cellValue;
    SchoolGrid.Model[rowIndex, columnIndex].DropDownStyle = GridDropDownStyle.Exclusive;
```

What I want to achieve is:

> 1)Items in combobox I want to show in "Gujarat/Surat" format. when
>   user select any item, the value that I want to be shown is only
>   "Surat", not "Gujarat/Surat".
>  2) When user open dropdown list, the
>   selected item should have focus.

In QueryCellInfo event, I've specified value for this column as "District"- property of my model.
In CommitCellInfo event, I am fetching and assigning the values to model properties. So point 1) is working as required. But I am not able to make point 2) working. I've tried using OnCurrentCellShowingDropDown, GotFocus events, but no luck.
How can I make it working?

Answer (score 0):

We have prepared the sample with your code snippet and checked the reported issue of “Focusing the selected item of ComboBox ”, but we were unable to reproduce the issue. Please find the sample link below:

**Sample:** [GridControl](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/210346/ze/WpfApplication31984579988)

If the issue still reproduces at your end, please modify the above sample to reproduce the issue and update us with the replication procedure. So that we will be able to analyze the issue better and update you with better solution.